# How to make vertical seekbar with progress text as thumb

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, android-seekbar

I want to create a vertical seekbar with progress displaying near to thumb.

[image: requirement]

I created vertical seekbar by overriding Seekbar class and rotate the canvas. But I don't know how to make the text near to thumb.

```
 @Override
protected final void onDraw(@NonNull final Canvas c) {
    if (null == mPaint) {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint.setTextSize(50);
    }
    c.rotate(ROTATION_ANGLE);
    c.translate(-getHeight(), 0);
    super.onDraw(c);
    Rect rect = getThumb().getBounds();
    c.drawText(getProgress()+"%", rect.exactCenterX(), rect.exactCenterY(), mPaint);
}
```

So the problem is If I drawText like this the text also rotated.
So how to fix this?

Meanwhile, I tried some custom View implementation and I am a noob on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update to Khemraj's answer**

Actually changing the thumb is the simple trick as said by Khemraj. But the problem is when **rotating the canvas** all its contents will rotate(simple logic). When updating the thumb also will reflect this problem. So the simple thing is to make a rotated `CustomTextView`.

> Method to make thumb

```
 public Drawable getThumb(int progress) {
    int width = getWidth();

    ((TextView) mThumbView.findViewById(R.id.tvProgress)).setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d%%", progress));
    mThumbView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mThumbView.getMeasuredWidth(), mThumbView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    mThumbView.layout(0, 0, mThumbView.getMeasuredWidth(), mThumbView.getMeasuredHeight());
    mThumbView.draw(canvas);
    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
}
```

> The layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/seek_thumb_gray"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.samsung.lighting.presentation.ui.custom_views.RotatedTextView
    android:id="@+id/tvProgress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="20%"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:angle="90"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> The `RotatedTextView`

```
public class RotatedTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
private int mRotationAngle = 90;


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mRotationAngle == 90) {
        canvas.rotate(mRotationAngle);
        canvas.translate(0, -getWidth());
    } else if (mRotationAngle == -90) {
        canvas.rotate(mRotationAngle);
        canvas.translate(-getHeight(), 0);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
} 
}
```

So first we will rotate the Text to 90 or -90 degrees and set as thumb to `VerticalSeekBar` and in vertical seekbar rotate the canvas to 90 or -90 degrees. So finally we will get the actual result

*Here I posted the working example.*

Thanks, Khemraj